# Why doesn't the background color change when I put a div in a div and set it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-color

I tried to change the background of a div element inside another div element, but nothing happens. When I look at the code with firebug it shows that the color had been changed but in my browser window I can't see any changes

HTML

```
<div id="outer" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <div id="inner" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%"></div> 
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function back(){
 $('#inner').css('background-color', 'yellow');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     back(); 
});
```

Comment: Because the div has no content to display?

Comment: Did your example work in plain HTML?

Comment: Hy,
which Version of jQuery are you using ?
I've run your code on my System and it worked fine ! Maybe check your includes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the height of the body and html...

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/B2A7V/1

---

Percentage height is in relation to its container.

In your case the inner div is trying to match the height of its container (*the outer div*), but what is the outer divs height ?

If they are just put inside an empty page the outer div's container is the body, which also needs to set its height to 100% (*along with html to be sure*).

So add `html,body {height:100%;}` and it should work..

Answer (score 3):

Put some content inside the div so that div will have a height of that content. Or try giving a minimum height for your div in your CSS.

In the below code i added min-height in the CSS

```
<div id="1" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <div id="2" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;min-height:50px;">    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Its really nice how fast and helpfull this community is

Answer (score 0):

IDs must start with an alpha character. You can not have CSS IDs that are purely numeric. In addition, you may need an absolute height rather than a %.

Comment: Keep in mind that HTML5 has lifted the non-numeric constrain on ids. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#concept-id

Comment: I know... but HTML5 is not real-life coding today. HTML6 may allow you to simply create divs via osmosis, that doesn't mean it's valid for use today.

Comment: HTML5 is not supported widely enough to be considered the ipso-facto method to use. If you are building HTML5-only sites.. more power to you. Many people must support HTML4 or xHTML at a minimum.